# Windows error 32 when uploading images - Django 1.5

Tags: django, image, python-2.7, shutil, os.path

Windows users that upload images to our website get the error "WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process".

I'm pretty certain that this is something to do with locking in Windows (c.f. [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/669767/how-to-delete-a-folder-in-python-when-error-32-is-present)) but I can't for the life of me figure out what other process is accessing the file image when I'm trying to delete it!

Here is the relevant code that causes the error (the error is thrown on the line `shutil.rmtree(file_path)`). When the files are submitted, they are resized using PIL before saving (c.f. save() code)

### models.py

- Overwrite Storage (which I overwrote)

  ```
  class OverwriteStorage(FileSystemStorage):

      def get_available_name(self, name):

          file_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, name))
          if os.path.isdir(file_path):
              shutil.rmtree(file_path)
              return name
  ```
- Overwritten save() method on the `Project` model

  ```
  def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None, update_fields=None):

      for image_field in ({'name': 'photo', 'size': (208, 208), 'method': 'thumbnail'},
                      {'name': 'cover', 'size': (960, 300), 'method': 'crop'}):

          field = getattr(self, image_field['name'])
          if field:
              if field_has_changed(self, image_field['name']):

                  image = Image.open(field.file)
                  if image.mode not in ('L', 'RGB'):
                      image = image.convert('RGB')

                  if image_field['method'] == 'resize':
                      image = image.resize(image_field['size'], Image.ANTIALIAS)
                  elif image_field['method'] == 'crop':
                      image = resize_and_crop(image, image_field['size'], crop_type='middle')
                  else:
                      image.thumbnail(image_field['size'], Image.ANTIALIAS)

                  # Save the thumbnail
                  temp_file = StringIO()
                  image.save(temp_file, 'png')
                  temp_file.seek(0)

                  # Save to the thumbnail field
                  suf = SimpleUploadedFile(os.path.split(field.name)[-1], temp_file.read(), content_type='image/png')
                  field.save(suf.name.split('.')[0] + '.png', suf, save=False)

      # Save this photo instance
      super(Member, self).save(
          force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update, using=using, update_fields=update_fields)
  ```

Comment: I think the issue is that your code is trying to delete a file when it
is being accessed by something else. Perhaps you forgot to close it
elsewhere?

Comment: Maybe trying to close the file before saving it?

Comment: Thanks for having a look, inserting the line `suf.close()` (valid closing method for django file objects according to the docs) before saving doesn't seem to do anything though.

Comment: where more precisely are you trying to close it? try again, close it, and then, between closing and saving, insert a breakpoint and verify the status of your file(opened/closed). I am pretty sure that this generates the error. Uploading does replace the old image, so maybe the image is opened when trying to delete it)

Comment: Using the pdb debugger I found that the `suf` file wasn't closed when saving (4th line from bottom of my code), but as I said before, `suf.close()` doesn't seem to work and the error appears even if no image is replaced.

Comment: I reckon this is more of a Django problem, the SimpleUploadedFile class isn't well documented so it's difficult to understand how it works...